# Skipping The Kayran fight

Tags: the-witcher-2

I tried so many times now, but most of the time the tentacles hit the Yrden spot but don't freeze. I managed to cut of 2 tentacles, but then I die. I used three potions.

Is there a way to skip the Kayran fight and go on with the story? Or do I have to do this fight?

Comment: Why the down vote?
Please tell me why the question is wrong.

Comment: You can't skip it as far as I know, though there might be some cheats or mods to allow this. If the tentacles aren't trapped, you're likely trying to trap the wrong tentacles, only the rear tentacles can be trapped. See [my post here for more information](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/22737/4103).

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Lokuzt's advice of changing the difficulty to easy, you can also make it even simpler by turning off "Difficult QTEs" in the options menu. This will help near the end of the fight.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is **No**

There is no actual way of skipping the Kayran fight.

Check guides for the fight and if you still are having problems there's one simple thing you can do.

1. Change difficulty to **"Easy"**
2. Profit

That's the best advise and answer I can give you. Good Luck!